# VBA Range.Replace not working

Tags: vba, excel

The selection is an excel worksheet cell containing the following formula:

```
=+'[FORECAST MARZO RESTRUCTURING ITALY 20170403 V3.xlsx]DETTAGLIO'!$BA$20
```

I run the following VBA code:

```
Selection.Replace what:="[FORECAST MARZO RESTRUCTURING ITALY 20170403 V3.xlsx]", _
Replacement:="[AQ_0617 - solo nuova 272.xlsx]" _
   , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat _
  :=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

After executing the code I expected the formula to become:

```
=+'[AQ_0617 - solo nuova 272.xlsx]DETTAGLIO'!$BA$20
```

But intead nothing happens. Any clues?

Comment: Is `AQ_0617 - solo nuova 272.xlsx` an open workbook? Do you use `On Error Resume Next`?

Comment: There is something different in the two strings.  I can't figure out what, but when I copy the text from the formula and paste it in vba, the replace works.  There is something different between the two.

Comment: When you say nothing happens, do you mean the `Replace` doesn't work? Or it does replace but no data updates? Do you not get an error when replacing? What if you step through with `F8`, does that get you anywhere?

Comment: I have created a Sub with the above code and replaces the string without a problem.

Comment: Nothing happens means that I get no error message and after code execution the formula is unchanged. The is no "on error resume next". The 2 xlsx files involved are both open when executing the code.

Comment: If I execute with F8, nothing happens, just like if I executes a=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The replace method doesn't work because the 2 excel files don't have the same sheets, i.e. the sheet `'[AQ_0617 - solo nuova 272.xlsx]DETTAGLIO'` doesn't exist. So if the replace method was executed the final formula would contain an invalid reference